# dx-select-box binding mysql with angular

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

Good day,

I'd like to binding MySQL database to the component dx-select-box from DevExtreme.
There is somehow using AngularJS approach.
Then, I need filter for country, state and city following that:

### Select-Box:

### Angular:

```
$scope.selectBoxProvinceOptions = {
        dataSource: serviceFilter,
        placeholder: 'Select a province',
        displayExpr: 'name',
        valueExpr: 'state',
        bindingOptions: {
            value: 'state'
        }
};
```

### Server Side

```
app.get('/filter', function (req, res) {

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, \n\
                GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

  connection.query(   
        " SELECT CI.country, CI.state, CI.city  " +
        "  FROM cities CI " 

    , function (err, rows) {    




    if (!err) {
        console.log("Database is connected... \n");
        console.log('The solution is: ', rows);


    } else {
        console.log("Error connecting database... \n");
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    }

    res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));        
});


});
```

Can I use this way to push the results into the select  box?

There is someone that knows how to do.

Thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExtreme is the client-side technology, so you can easy integrate it with MySQL or another data base without any special JavaScript code.

For example, if you use MySQL + PHP, your backend-code can be like below:

```
// my-data-service.php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','user','password');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($result);
```

Now, in the client-side you can use the `my-data-service.php` url to load data:

```
var dataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource("/my-data-service.php");
```

Next, bind the `dataSource` instance to `dxSelectBox` or some another devextreme-widget.

Comment: Sergey, 
I edited my question. I put my piece of code in the server side. Thanks!